# New syntax for default values in Swift functions

Tags: cocoa, swift2, default-value

I just noticed that the latest beta of `Xcode` (7.1) has changed the signature for the `print` function in `Swift`.

The new syntax is:

```
public func print(items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default)
```

Anybody knows what this `default` thing is? How do you specify the default value, not just the fact that it has one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` in the function signature means that it has a default value and you don't have to pass a parameter.

```
func add(a: Int = 0, b: Int = 0) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

// "normal" function call
add(2, b: 4) // 6

// no specified parameters at all
add() // 0; both a and b default to 0

// one parameter specified
// a has no external name since it is the first parameter
add(3) // 3; b defaults to 0
// b has an external name since it is not the first parameter
add(b: 4) // 4; a defaults to 0
```

In case of the `print` function `separator` defaults to `" "` and `terminator` to `"\n"`.

There are 4 way to call it:

```
struct SomeItem {}
print(SomeItem(), SomeItem())
print(SomeItem(), SomeItem(), separator: "_")
print(SomeItem(), SomeItem(), terminator: " :) \n")
print(SomeItem(), SomeItem(), separator: "_", terminator: " :) \n")
```

Prints:

```
SomeItem() SomeItem()
SomeItem()_SomeItem()
SomeItem() SomeItem() :)
SomeItem()_SomeItem() :)
```

Answer (score 1):

the default `separator` is a single space, and the default `terminator` is a newline

to use a different value for either of these, simply pass the desired value as an argument when you call the function - e.g.:

```
print("first", "second", separator: "-", terminator: "...")
print("third")
// => "first-second...third"
```